# How convert UInt and others types to String Hex to send data to a server? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, uwp, hex

Details about the application:

- Developed under Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10)
- Designed on `UWP` platform with `C#` & `XAML` language

The application receives information from a remote server. A connection with sockets is used for communication between the two parties.

To communicate with the server, the application must send the data in a Byte Array so that it can be read correctly.

I need to pass these variables to String Hex and then I have a method to pass String Hex to Byte Array.

Variables to send :

```
 UInt16 ID_MESSAGE = 201;
 SByte ID_WAY = -1;
 UInt16 SIZE = 16;

 enum TYPE_STATE_DEVICE
 {
    LOGOUT = 0,
    OUT_OF_ORDER,
    LOGIN,
    REPLAY
 };
```

How I can pass these variables in hexadecimal to find the same values ​​below?

Here are the values ​​that the variables must have in hexadecimal:

```
ID_MESSAGE = C9-00-00-00
ID_WAY = FF-FF-FF-FF
SIZE = 10-00-00-00
TYPE_STATE_DEVICE.LOGIN = 02-00-00-00
```

So the complete String Hex must be like this:

```
HexString = C9-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-10-00-00-00-02-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your values into a byte array and then use the BitConverter class to convert it into a string.

```
var ID_MESSAGE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)ID_MESSAGE);
var ID_WAY_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)ID_WAY);
var SIZE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)SIZE);
var TYPE_STATE_DEVICE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)TYPE_STATE_DEVICE.LOGIN);

var HexString = BitConverter.ToString(ID_MESSAGE_ARRAY.Concat(ID_WAY_ARRAY).Concat(SIZE_ARRAY).Concat(TYPE_STATE_DEVICE_ARRAY).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your first response before edit work perfeclty execpt for one case. In ID_WAY array i have : FF-00-00-00 and not FF-FF-FF-FF like i want. Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: I have also a bool `bool RIGHT = false` how i can pass it to byte array ?

Comment: After my edit you can see that `ID_WAY` is correctly converted to `FF-FF-FF-FF`. For your `bool RIGHT = false` you can do it in the same way as the other arrays are constructed. `BitConverter.GetBytes(RIGHT ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: Yeah it works. I take advantage of one last question. I have `string Adress = "192.54.185.58"`  I need to pass it in `string[32]` and then in bytes, how I can do this ? Thanks for your response

Comment: Your comment is unclear. you can convert `string` to `char[]` using `Adress.ToCharArray()` or depending on your Encoding, you can use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Adress)` to convert it to a `byte[]` that you can then use in conjunction with `BitConverter.ToString(...)`. Or you can parse the individual parts of the IP as bytes (cause thats what they are) `Adress.Split('.').Select(b => byte.Parse(b)).ToArray()`.

Comment: I made another post about the problem, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288583/convert-string-to-string-and-then-convert-string-to-byte