# Convert string to string[] and then convert string[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, byte

Details about the application:

- Developed under Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10)
- Designed on `UWP` platform with `C#` & `XAML` language

The application receives information from a remote server. A connection with sockets is used for communication between the two parties.

To communicate with the server, the application must send the data in a Byte Array so that it can be read correctly.

Currently I use this method to pass my variables in bytes[]:

```
var ID_MESSAGE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)MESSAGE);
var WAY_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)WAY);
var SIZE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)SIZE);
var TYPE_STATE_DEVICE_ARRAY = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)TYPE_STATE_DEVICE.LOGIN);

var HexString = ID_MESSAGE_ARRAY.Concat(WAY_ARRAY).Concat(SIZE_ARRAY).Concat(TYPE_STATE_DEVICE_ARRAY).Concat(ABO).ToArray();
```

As a result of this message, I have to send a `string`. So I use this method to code my `string` into `bytes[]` :

```
string ABONNE = "TEST";
var ABO = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ABONNE);
```

But I have a problem, this `string` must be on 32 bytes, whereas when I decode (hexa) on the other side I find this:

Obtained result : `54-45-53-54`

Expected result : `54-45-53-54-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00`

To find this result, how can I pass my `string ABONNE` in `string[32]` and then in `bytes[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about if you pass your string to 32 bytes array directly:

```
string ABONNE = "TEST";
Byte[] ABO = new byte[32];
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ABONNE,0,ABONNE.Length,ABO,0);
```

Both zeros are for 0-index (start position). Also I have created a 32 bytes array empty, than then it is filled with the bytes from `ABONNE`. **Please be carefull that if `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ABONNE).Length` is greather than 32 bytes, you will get an exception**

Comment: Was writing the same: here is [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_) on this particular overload

Comment: `var ABO` returns an `int` and not a `byte[]`

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot I have changed the variables names using yours

Comment: @val , Some GetBytes return `byte[]` but if you pass in parameter the byte pointer  or bytes array they have to write on they return `int` the number of byte wrote.

Comment: @xdtTransform Thanks for the help, @ ganchito55 to change his answer and it works perfectly

Comment: @ganchito55 do you have a solution to pass `bool t = false` to a `byte[4]` ? Thanks

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot please open another question with the input and the expected output and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Use `StringBuilder` to pad your string with a necessary number of nulls.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ABONNE);
sb.Append((char)0,32-ABONNE.Length);
```

**Updated** a working example instead of a pseudo-code.

Comment: The 0 will result in a hexa code of 30, right so the array wiil be padded with 30 30 30 insteand of 00 00 00

Comment: @xdtTransform That's not a character '0' it's character \0.

Comment: confusion was born from the pseudo code as there where no overload that took int like this. I was left with it's either `0` or `(char)0`.